# How can I combine implementations of a trait for Vec<T> as well as Vec<&T>

Tags: rust

I have a trait that I own:

```
trait Reducer {
  fn reduce(&self) -> Res;
}
```

I want to implement for the following cases:

```
struct MyStruct {... fields ...}

impl Reducer for Vec<MyStruct> {
  fn reduce(&self) -> Res { ... some implementation ... }
}
```

I want to get for as cheap as possible (not duplicating code etc.) for the refs of objects in Vec:

for instance:

```
// I want this please:

impl Reducer for Vec<&MyStruct> {
  // it's the same implementation as before
}
```

How should I change my `impl` signature to satisfy both cases?

Comment: I see many libraries use a macro for this that just copies the same code for both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`Borrow` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) you can generalize for all types that can be borrowed as a `&MyStruct` (which in particular includes `MyStruct` and `&MyStruct`):

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

trait Reducer {
  fn reduce(&self) -> Res;
}

struct MyStruct;
struct Res;

impl<T: Borrow<MyStruct>> Reducer for Vec<T> {
    fn reduce(&self) -> Res {
        for t in self {
            let _t: &MyStruct = t.borrow();
            // do something with `_t`
        }
        Res
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<MyStruct> = vec![];
    let v_ref: Vec<&MyStruct> = vec![];

    // fully qualified because it gets mangled with `Iterator::reduce` otherwise.
    Reducer::reduce(&v);
    Reducer::reduce(&v_ref);
}
```

Comment: Or `AsRef` in case you don't need `Borrow`'s guarantees.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yeah, `AsRef` is probably better, I went with `Borrow` on account of its blanket impl.

Answer (score 1):

If your reducer only needs to iterate over the items in the `Vec`, then there is no difference between `Vec<T>` and `Vec<&T>` because both can easily produce an iterator over `&T`. For example:

```
// actual implementation
fn reduce_it<'a>(_items: impl Iterator<Item = &'a MyStruct>) -> Res {
    todo!()
}

impl Reducer for Vec<MyStruct> {
    fn reduce(&self) -> Res {
        reduce_it(self.iter())
    }
}

impl Reducer for Vec<&MyStruct> {
    fn reduce(&self) -> Res {
        reduce_it(self.iter().copied())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bc7f3feefa526735b22a0b15cbce5dca)